# Extremely slow write to USB 2.0, EXT4, from Linux Mint

Tags: usb, performance, linux-mint

When used first time, write to USB gave only 200Kb/sec speed o.O Like 3 hours for 300MB copy.

I formatted the USB as EXT4, and tried again, the speed went up to 1.6MB/sec, but then quickly fell down to 400KB. Sure, it's wayyyy better but still cannot believe this is the way to make large copies of several GBs. Am I missing something? I mean, if I need a backup for my Home, it would take me whole night.

Comment: What kind of USB device is it, a hard drive? flash drive? A spinning drive can be quite slow.

Comment: Can you invoke `lsusb -t`? On my Kubuntu it displays e.g. `Driver = ehci-pci/2p`. *The OHCI/UHCI are the two industry standard USB 1.1 interfaces whereas EHCI is for USB 2.0 and xHCI is compatible with all of the previously mentioned interfaces including USB 3.0* ([source](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/USB/Guide#A_technical_perspective)). Confirm the bus you use is seen as EHCI.

Comment: It's a flash drive. The `lsusb -t` tells me it's xHCI driver, 2 of them actually, one 8p 5000M (dont know what is that) and another one 16p 480M

Answer (score 0):

Before digging into your software, you need to benchmark your pen drive. Go get access to a Windows computer, and run a benchmark like this [ATTO bench](https://www.atto.com/disk-benchmark/), you might be surprised finding actual speed of your write operations on a low-end pen drive.

If you see write speeds on large data blocks in 2-3MBps range, throw it away and get one of [USB 3.0 dual or quad-channel pen drives](http://www.futurelooks.com/patriot-memory-flash-drive-shootout-usb-2-0-vs-usb-3-0-quad-channel-vs-usb-3-0-8-channel/), they will perform up to full theoretical USB 2.0 speed (~35 MBps) on USB 2.0 controller.

Comment: oh. Well after test ( `dd if=blabla of=blabla`), it turns out I have 15 MB/s read, and 3.1 MB/s write. But still, it would be great to achieve them IRL, not only during test